# Colspan to match row above that hides td's based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table row that will hide td's that have a class of "HideTdSmallScreen" and would like to make the colspan for the table below match the number of viable td's above. Sometime 7 td's are visible and sometimes only 5 are.

```
  <tr>
        <td>Hill Top</td>
        <td class="HideTdSmallScreen">Tues</td>
        <td class="HideTdSmallScreen"> 9.00- 5.00</td>
        <td> 2020</td>
        <td> 1   </td>
        <td> £35 </td>  
        <td>     </td> 
  </tr

<tr>
    <td colspan="7">
        <p>Message</p>                                                                          
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can try it with JS, using children length function of jQuery you can count the number of td's in the upper row and according to that you can set the colspan of second row using any unique class or id for second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function changeColspan(){
  var screenMax = 599;
  var colspan = 7;
  if ( $( window ).width() < screenMax ){
    var displayedTdS = $('.reference-row td:not(.HideTdSmallScreen)');
    if (displayedTdS){
      colspan = displayedTdS.length;
    }
  } 
  $('.changed-row').attr('colspan', colspan);
}

$( window ).on('resize', changeColspan);

changeColspan();
```

This jQuery code should do it assuming your first row has the class `reference-row` and the second one the `changed-row`.

The screenMax variable is the width under which the td-s are hidden, and the colspan is the default colspan.